# 'Automatic brightness' option is missing, is there has any alternatives?

Tags: brightness

On the previous versions of ubuntu, there was an 'Automatic brightness' option to turn off/on the automatic brightness. Now this option from 'power saving' is missing and I want to turn off the automatic brightness control, how am I supposed to turn it off?

Comment: This seems to be dependent on the hardware, which is odd. I just checked my Lenovo ThinkPad and found that it no longer has this feature anymore, while it was part of 20.04. Could you [edit] your question to include the brand/model of your computer and, if applicable, which video hardware you're using? This will make it more likely that someone can offer an answer 

Comment: You reference previous version but make no mention of the version you are using.